# Matlab different linewith of marker and errorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to set different linewidth for marker and for error bar. Is there a set call for that or maybe a custom functon? The documentation only says that markersize affects the error bar width as weel.

here's a fraction of my code:

```
s = subplot(1,5,r);
if any(imDATA(r,1,1))
errorbar(imDATA(r,19:26,1), imDATA(r,3:10,1), imDATA(r,27:34,1),'-'k','MarkerSize',e,'LineWidth',w)
hold on;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`errorbar` returns a handle to the created objects, you can change those if you want later on. The handle is a group containing both the errorbars as the plot of the data (eg connecting line).

Inspect this handle with [get](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and you'll see that you can change them individually:

```
x = 0:pi/3:pi;
y = sin(x);
h=errorbar(x,y,e,'rx:')
hchildren = get(h,'children');
set(hchildren(1), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'b')
set(hchildren(2), 'LineWidth', 3, 'Color', 'g');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Dafsa Can you then include the code that generates the errorbar. If I use the code from your OP, then `errorbar` does generate two children.

Comment: Thats interesting, because Matlab documentation says: 
Children — Children of errorbar series
empty GraphicsPlaceholder array
The errorbar series has no children. You cannot set this property.

Maybe its a matter of version? I am using 2015a